# Fill width with two divs, one of which might be absent

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a very basic chat system, part of which will be the entry box for lines of chat. If the user is logged in, that's all I need; but if the user is not logged in, I want an additional text box to allow them to enter their name.

I have the following HTML (although of course it can be altered):

```
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name?" name="name" id="name"> <!-- This line may be absent -->
  <input type="text" placeholder="What do you want to say?" name="say" id="say">
</form>
```

Is it possible to style this with CSS so that `#name` and `#say` together fill the whole width of the `form`, with `#say` taking all the width if `#name` is absent?

(The backend is Ruby on Rails; I have javascript available, so can use a JS solution, but would prefer pure CSS if possible)

Comment: based on the context, I imagine you'll be using a programming language (php, javascript) to do a lot of this? what other information can you give us?

Comment: @DouglasMarken - Fair point. Added in that it's RoR w/ JS available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple, **all-CSS solution**, try the first-child pseudo-selector to overide a default half-width when #say is the first element inside of the form:

```
#name, #say{width:100px}
#say:first-child{width:200px}
```

This works perfectly fine with your simple markup structure. (I've tested it)

Comment: That's the ticket! It's even compatible down to IE7! You win 1 internet.

Answer (score 1):

With whichever of the two languages you'll be using to determine whether the user is logged in, create a conditional statement that adds a html class to the input field that alters it's width say .input-full and .input-partial

```
IF user is logged in
    SET class to input-full
ELSE
    SET class to input-partial
ENDIF
```

sorry for the psedo code, then have appropriate CSS for each.

oooh, didn't see the CSS only, sorry. Without CSS3 and a disregard for IE I don't think you can do this with straight CSS.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll go down this route.